# Methods to use constructor injection in user controls?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, dependency-injection

Are there any ways to enforce or allow constructor required dependencies for a user control without breaking the designer? What work arounds exist?

a default constructor with [EditorBrowsable.Never](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx)
or property injection, but I prefer constructor injection.

other work-arounds or solutions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Design user controls so that they **don't use dependencies**.

Look at the controls (ASP.NET, Windows Forms, WPF, etc.) supplied by Microsoft. None of them use dependencies. Instead, you **assign data** to them - often by way of writable properties.

This is a more [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) design because a control's **single responsibility** should be to **render data**. Thus, if you also give it the responsibility of retrieving or formatting data, you are breaking the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

When you design controls like that, a default constructor becomes natural.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this one Mark, I'm looking forward to your book, it's late enough at night that I want to think about this for a bit. My gut reaction is that I hate microsoft's designs for making it so hard to use immutability or a functional style. I want valid state at all times if possible. I'm intrigued by the idea of SRP'ing out data, display, formatting, and retrieval in winForms. Does that suggest 4+ classes for each control? If it changes anything, this is a VERY specific user control that is unlikely to be reused except on the form it was designed for twice.

Comment: Well, I can't say how many classes you'd end up with, but reuse isn't always the end-goal. On another note, I totally agree with your views about Microsoft's designs.

Comment: what if you want to add a logging manager to log events, such as control_load, or control_resize?  If I cannot inject the logging manager, then I must "new" one up in the user control itself.  It seems to me resizing the screen is presentation concern and as such it follows 'SOLID' principles...

Comment: @barrypicker Are those _events?_

Comment: @barrypicker In that case, why would you need to to _inject_ a 'logging manager' to subscribe to those events?

Answer (score 3):

You can overload constructors.  The designer is going to require the default constructor at design time so be sure to supply that one as well.

```
    public UserControl1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public UserControl1(Foo arg) : this() {
        // Do something with arg
        //...
    }
```

Of course, the client code has to create that user control itself.  Favor properties to keep the user control useful in the designer.  Throw an exception in OnLoad() if DesignMode is false and you're not happy about the way the client code used your control.

Comment: yes I know you can overload constructors that's the reason I already included the solution of using EditorBrowsable.Never. I was referring to putting that on the default constructor. I'm looking for something more detailed, DRY, and defensive - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming

Comment: I don't know what you are looking for.  Program defensively by using the normal control patterns instead of trying to come up with something custom that confuses the heck out of the client programmer.  You can help by creating a custom designer.